# mutil dimension matrix addition

Tags: multidimensional-array, matrix

For my class we had to do  a project in which the user can assign upto 4 matrices A B C D and then display it using malloc. Now I want to go to the next part and also give the user to add whichever matrix he wants. This is my code that is running perfectly to store and display matrices:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void matrix_display(int ****matrix, int row_count, int column_count);


int main (void)
{
int row_size1,col_size1,row_size2,col_size2,flag =1;
int ****A[4];
int i = 0, j = 0;
char a,c;


do
{
printf("\ncmd> ");
c = getchar();


if(c == 'A')
{
scanf("%d %d",&row_size1,&col_size1);
A[0]= malloc(row_size1*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
A[0][i]=malloc(col_size1*sizeof(int));
}
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col_size1;j++)
    {
scanf("%d",&A[0][i][j]);


    }
}
matrix_display(A[0], row_size1, col_size1);
  }


if(c == 'B')
{
scanf("%d %d",&row_size1,&col_size1);
A[1]= malloc(row_size1*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
A[1][i]=malloc(col_size1*sizeof(int));
}
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col_size1;j++)
  {
scanf("%d",&A[1][i][j]);


       }
   }
matrix_display(A[1], row_size1, col_size1);
}


if(c == 'C')
{
scanf("%d %d",&row_size1,&col_size1);
A[2]= malloc(row_size1*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
A[2][i]=malloc(col_size1*sizeof(int));
}
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col_size1;j++)
 {
scanf("%d",&A[2][i][j]);


       }
   }
matrix_display(A[2], row_size1, col_size1);
}


if(c == 'D')
{
scanf("%d %d",&row_size1,&col_size1);
A[3]= malloc(row_size1*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
A[3][i]=malloc(col_size1*sizeof(int));
}
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col_size1;j++)
 {
scanf("%d",&A[3][i][j]);


       }
   }
matrix_display(A[3], row_size1, col_size1);
 }


 }
while(flag == 1);
 }


void matrix_display(int ****A, int row_size1, int col_size1) 
{
int i,j;
printf("The required matrix is\n");
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<col_size1;j++)
  printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
for(i=0;i<row_size1;i++)
{
  free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
}
```

Now for the addition part I have added this:
this is how I want it to run:
cmd> + A D
(displays the addition of matrix A and D)

I don't know how to do this any advice would be appreciated

I know that their are easier ways to do this and **** I used aren't used but please make an exception this time